# How to trigger Jenkins build using the Python package JenkinsAPI?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job set up with the name `Test2` which I can build from Jenkins web interface. Now I want to trigger that build using JenkinsAPI. I have only been able to find example code to do other things but the [API Documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jenkinsapi/latest/jenkinsapi.pdf) mentions the `Build` class. So I thought I would try to instantiate it and then wait for it to complete (hoping that would also trigger the actual build) but I am getting rather cryptic errors much earlier than that. What am I doing wrong?

```
import jenkinsapi
b = jenkinsapi.build.Build("http://localhost:8080", 1, "test2")
b.block_until_complete()
```

Gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathan/Genetta/Eclipse_Django_workspace/FOO/foo/TriggerBuild.py", line 2, in <module>
    b = jenkinsapi.build.Build("http://localhost:8080", 1, "test2")
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/build.py", line 58, in __init__
    JenkinsBase.__init__(self, url)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.poll()
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 59, in poll
    data = self._poll(tree=tree)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/build.py", line 65, in _poll
    return self.get_data(url, params={'depth': self.depth}, tree=tree)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 72, in get_data
    requester = self.get_jenkins_obj().requester
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/build.py", line 371, in get_jenkins_obj
    return self.job.get_jenkins_obj()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_jenkins_obj'
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me why your example isn't working, but I find the JenkinsAPI documentation confusing in general so perhaps I just don't get it.

I've found that to get a particular build directly, you can use the [`get_build` method](http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/api.html#jenkinsapi.api.get_build) in the api package. The arguments are in a different order:

```
import jenkinsapi
b = jenkinsapi.api.get_build("http://localhost:8080", "Test 1", 1)
```

This is fine for existing builds, started through some other means. But it sounds like you actually want to trigger a build. In that case, get the job through a Jenkins instance and use the `invoke` method:

```
import jenkinsapi
jenkins = jenkinsapi.jenkins.Jenkins("http://192.168.99.100:8080")
job = jenkins["Test 1"]
job.invoke(block=True)
```

In my opinion, there is little benefit to using a confusingly documented interface package (why are there multiple ways to get a build?) when the plain Jenkins REST API can be accessed via the *requests* package as described by [massiou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913411/172599).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I found online different ways of triggering build (some worked some didn't). Yours helped. Curious where did you find it? Official python jenkinsapi doc isn't quite exhaustive. Where did you find?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using jenkinsapi module, you could trigger your job simply request jenkins REST api like follows:

```
import requests 

# Case job has no parameter
job_url = "http://localhost:8080/job/test2/build"

# Job with parameters
job_url = "http://localhost:8080/job/test2/buildWithParameters?param1=value1&param2=value2"

status = requests.get(job_url)
```

Comment: You must use POST method to trigger builds