# Content-Type incorrect using Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, jenkins, http-headers, python-requests

I am attempting to kick off a paramaterized Jenkins job using the Python Requests library (2.17.3 and Python 3.6) but I am running into issues.

I have tested with Curl and it works and kicks off the Jenkins job like I would expect.  The following is a simplified version of the curl command I used.

```
curl -X POST -H "$crumb" $jenkins_url/job/$job_name/build?token=$job_token \
  --user $auth \
  --data-urlencode json='
  {"parameter":
    [
      {"name":"parameter1", "value":"test1"},
      {"name":"parameter2", "value":"test2"},
      {"name":"git_repo", "value":"'$my_repo'"},
      {"name":"git_tag", "value":"'$git_tag'"}
    ]
  }'
```

Doing the same thing with Python though is causing problems.  Here is (basically) what I'm doing in Python.

```
import requests
job_url = JENKINS_URL + "/job/" + JOB_NAME + "/build?token=" + JOB_TOKEN
params = {
    "parameter":
    [
  {"name":"parameter1", "value":"test1"},
  {"name":"parameter2", "value":"test2"},
  {"name":"git_repo", "value":"'$my_repo'"},
  {"name":"git_tag", "value":"'$git_tag'"}
    ]
}
job = requests.post(job_url, headers=headers, auth=(JENKINS_USER, JENKINS_PASS), data=params)
```

And when I examine the response, I get `Error 400 This page expects a form submission` in the returned `job.content`.  Looking at the content-type in the job object I see that it is set to `text/html` which doesn't seem right, but I don't know why it doesn't respect the header that is supposed to get set.

```
print(job.headers)
{'Server': 'nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Sat, 10 Jun 2017 01:57:04 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1', 'Content-Length': '392', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONIDXXX;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly', 'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store'}
```

I have tried setting the `Content-Type` header manually in the code but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: i think you're printing the response headers, not the request headers, so i don't think that's relevant. you might look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913411/6090676. it's using buildWithParameters, which i know you're saying isn't required, since your curl worked without it, but you might get it to work that way (using query parameters).

Comment: @burnettk It looks like it works with `buildWithParamaters`, I'll probably just go with that.

Comment: super, added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `/buildWithParameters` instead of `/build` like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913411/6090676. you can specify parameters in the url as query parameters. you'll love it. :)